# Changing content created with ContentTools library in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, content-tools

What I want to do is change the content that has been created with content tools by using javascript.

For example:

```
<div data-editable data-name="content">
    <p id='p-text'>This is a paragrahp</p>
</div>
```

```
document.getElementById("p-text").innerHTML = "Hello World"
```

When I execute this javacript code in that html it changes the value. But the moment when I hit the save button it returns to the old state. It seems like ContentTools does not notice that I have made a change. There is a definetly way to do this because content tools has an tool to change the innerhtml of the elment in the properties dialog. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1):

Your way of changing the inner HTML is a correct, vanilla JS based solution. But, you want to be able to set this value on save button.

Refer the documentation: https://getcontenttools.com/getting-started

It has this example for a `saved` event:

```
editor.addEventListener('saved', function (ev) {
    var name, payload, regions, xhr;

    // Check that something changed
    regions = ev.detail().regions;
    if (Object.keys(regions).length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Set the editor as busy while we save our changes
    this.busy(true);

    // Collect the contents of each region into a FormData instance
    payload = new FormData();
    for (name in regions) {
        if (regions.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            payload.append(name, regions[name]);
        }
    }

    // Send the update content to the server to be saved
    function onStateChange(ev) {
        // Check if the request is finished
        if (ev.target.readyState == 4) {
            editor.busy(false);
            if (ev.target.status == '200') {
                // Save was successful, notify the user with a flash
                new ContentTools.FlashUI('ok');
            } else {
                // Save failed, notify the user with a flash
                new ContentTools.FlashUI('no');
            }
        }
    };

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', onStateChange);
    xhr.open('POST', '/save-my-page');
    xhr.send(payload);
});
```

It does an AJAX post, but you can do something else instead, like writing into `localStorage` or whatever fits your scenario the best. The idea is that either you create a `saved` event and properly trigger that with your save button, or, you can modify the save button's click event to post/save your changes. Now, whenever the save completes, which may be a page load, or a callback function, you can set the `innerHTML` to the proper value like you did in your tests.

Comment: But the point is I want to save it as I changed the content with javascript. The only way to get the content when save button is clicked is (as you mentioned) `ev.detail().regions;`. But content-tools don't notice that I have changed someing when I do it with javascript so it  does not returns any `region` to the event handler. Even if it returns the `region` (I just removed some conditions from the source code to test it) it returns the old state of the content not the javscript changed state. It only returns the new `region` if the user changed someting by using editor itself.